# Prove that if matrix $~A^2 = I~$, then $~A~$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have to prove that for $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C} )  $ , if $A^2 = I$,  then $A$ is diagonalizable.

I have no direction what so ever, Please help.

Comment: If you don't know what direction you're supposed to go, then try going in *any* direction. What general facts do you know about matrices? What can you discover by experimenting with the equation $A^2 = I$? What facts do you know about diagonalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A$ is a root of $x^{2} - 1$, which has distinct roots. Now [the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^{2} - 1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29#Formal_definition), and so it has distinct roots too. [This implies that $A$ is diagonalizable.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29#Applications)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Either $A= \pm I$ or $X^2-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: how do I know that $X^2 - 1$ is the minimal polynomial of A? if I don't know what A is...

Comment: @DorShalom: Because the minimal polynomial $P$ of $A$ divides $X^2-1=(X+1)(X-1)$, so $P=X+1$, $X-1$ or $X^2-1$. Therefore, if $A \neq \pm I$, then $P=X^2-1$.